# Dojo 1.9.4 not installed in Notes Client and Domino Designer 9.0.1 FP2 IF1?

Tags: dojo, installation, xpages, domino-designer-eclipse

First I installed 9.0.1 FP2 IF1 on the server (901FP2HF384_W64) and I was told that this would make dojo 1.9.4 the default dojo, but it was not. I needed to add xsp.client.script.dojo.version=1.9.4 to my XSP Property file to get it to work

Next I need dojo 1.9.4 on the client as well, both as xpinc and when doing preview in web browser so I installed first FP2 IF1 (901FP2SHF63_W32_standard) and later on also FP2 IF3 (901FP2SHF63_W32_standard) but none of these fixes seem to have added dojo 1.9.4

I did try to add xsp.client.script.dojo.version=1.9.4 to my application but I get the following error in both xpinc and preview in web-browser

**No Dojo library found matching the configured Dojo library version xsp.client.script.dojo.version=1.9.4.**

I ran the following code in a repeat...
**com.ibm.xsp.context.DojoLibraryFactory.getDefaultLibrary().getVersion()**

...and found out the following

**Dojo installed using Preview in webbrowser**

1.8.3
1.5.2
1.8.3
1.5.2

**Dojo Installed using xpinc**

1.9.2
1.5.2
1.9.2
1.5.2

What am I doing wrong here, Why is the fixes not installing 1.9.4? and how can I get 1.9.4 (same as on server) without installing separate dojo packages

Related
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21686751

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the first issue, you should definitely not need the xsp property to apply dojo 1.9.4, it should be the default. We have not come across any issue with this, thus I'm not sure what the problem is that you are experiencing. Perhaps try uninstalling & reinstalling the IF and/or FP2 and/or both?

On the Notes client issues: The 9.0.1 FP2 Interim Fix 1 fixed an iOS8 issue on the server (for XPages mobile controls) by upgrading dojo to 1.9.4 - http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21657963#Domino

At present there is no Interim Fix that upgrades the dojo version on the Client - http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21657963#Notes. There is no use case involving the use of XPages Mobile controls in the client, so the dojo version in the client was left untouched. It was actually unprecedented to upgrade dojo in an Interim Fix, but the severity of the iOS8 issue meant it needed to be done on the server.

You could manually copy the "com.ibm.xsp.dojo" folder from the server over to your Notes install to have 1.9.4 on both server and client

Comment: Thank you Brian for your clarification about this, I thought for a while that the new bootstrap theme required the new dojo but now I know that it does not. I am used to only do development with preview in webbrowser so that is where I was testing the mobile controls which then was failing if I specify dojo 1.9.4. long story short: Your answer helped a lot.